# Python / Selenium script behaves differently each time I run it

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Windows 10, Selenium 3.141.59, geckodriver 64-bit 0.26, python 3.7.1

I upload serial numbers to Cisco (https://cway.cisco.com/sncheck/ which redirects to a Cisco identity log in page) to ensure maintenance coverage. I am trying to automate this task using python code and selenium. I got my script to work, ran it a second time and got an error message:

"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined" error message.

I made no changes, and it ran fine 3 or 4 more times. Then gave the "rect is undefined" error several times in a row. I've cleared the browser cache, restarted my machine . . .nothing seems to effect whether it works or  not, just seems random. Here's the code I am running.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\work\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\work\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:\\work\\selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe")

driver.get("http://cway.cisco.com/sncheck/") 

assert "Cisco.com" in driver.title

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.url_changes("https://cway.cisco.com/sncheck/"))

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("pf.username")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(elem).perform()

elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("myuserIDhere")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

assert "No result Found" not in driver.page_source
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.url_contains("https://identity.cisco.com/"))

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(elem).perform()

elem.send_keys("a-real-password-here")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I've tried to run this script 5 times since I began this post. It returned the "rect undefined" the first 3 times, worked once, then returned the "rect undefined" the last time. I tried the same code with Chrome and the chrome driver and the same same sort of thing happens: it fails 4 out of 5 times but with a DIFFERENT error code:

(selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined).

I then tried IE, and it worked, including passing the "password" but it was very slow, passing one character about every 6 seconds. Then, without any change to the code, it began to work off and on returning this error code:

(selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == [name="password"]).

I don't care about "fixing" this code, maybe it's just poorly written. Any help would be appreciated.

Steve

Comment: Which lines in the python code seen to be throwing the exceptions?

Comment: When I went to the URL just now it redirects to https://cloudsso.cisco.com/as/authorization.oauth2?client_id=generic.cway.cisco.com&redirect_uri=https://cway.cisco.com/ws/oauth/v4/sso/login&scope=openid+email+profile&response_type=token. Selenium can choke on redirects. Usually going directly to the page rather than to the page that returns the redirect is the more reliable approach.

Comment: The rect error probably has to do with move_to... if you don't need the move_to or clear actions, leave those out.  Sending keys will set focus and all of that... the waits you are currently using aren't necessary.  Selenium will already wait for pageloads.  Use the webdriverwaits on finding the elements you are going to interact with.  (Wait for element to be interactable for text fields...)

Comment: Use WebDriverWait to wait element visibility for every elements.